# TKinter scrollbar not scrolling all the way down

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have managed to get a scrollbar working in TKinter. However, it does not scroll down all the way down to the contents of the page. Here is a MWE of what I have

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import Tk

fontcolor = '#3a346f'

class SecurityProperties(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        # Set up scroll bar
        self.main_frame = Frame(self, bg = "white")
        self.main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.my_canvas = Canvas(self.main_frame, bg = "white")
        self.my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.my_scrollbar=ttk.Scrollbar(self.main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.my_canvas.yview)
        self.my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.my_scrollbar.set)
        self.my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.my_canvas.bbox("all")))

        self.second_frame = Frame(self.my_canvas, width=1000, height=500, bg = "white")
        self.my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.second_frame, anchor= "nw")
    
        helv15 = font.Font(family="Helvetica",size=15,weight="bold")
        helv10 = font.Font(family="Helvetica",size=10,weight="bold")

        self.UpperTextBox = Label(self.second_frame, bg = "white", relief = GROOVE, text = "Information on channel characteristics and security of finite keys", font = helv15, fg = fontcolor)
        self.UpperTextBox.place(relheight = 0.15, relwidth = 0.8, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)

        # Output values - Row 1
        self.row1 = Label(self.second_frame, bg = "white", relief = GROOVE, text = "Row1", font = helv10, fg = fontcolor)
        self.row1.place(relheight = 0.15, relwidth = 0.2, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.35)

        # Row 2
        self.row2 = Label(self.second_frame, bg = "white", relief = GROOVE, text = "Row2", font = helv10, fg = fontcolor)
        self.row2.place(relheight = 0.15, relwidth = 0.2, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.6)

        # Row 3
        self.row3 = Label(self.second_frame, bg = "white", relief = GROOVE, text = "Row3", font = helv10, fg = fontcolor)
        self.row3.place(relheight = 0.15, relwidth = 0.2, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.85)

        # Row 4
        self.row4 = Label(self.second_frame, bg = "white", relief = GROOVE, text = "Row4", font = helv10, fg = fontcolor)
        self.row4.place(relheight = 0.15, relwidth = 0.2, relx = 0.1, rely = 1.1)
```

What is the mistake here to be able to see the `row4` Label?

Comment: `rely = 1.1` is placing `row4` entirely outside the bounds of the Frame.  Note that this is a problem that can only happen with `.place()` - if you used `.pack()` or `.grid()`, they would manage the container size for you.

Comment: @jasonharper, that makes sense thank you. How can I achieve the equivalent using `.pack()` or `.grid()` as you suggested? Could you write a small example?

Comment: Using `.pack()`  you'll only get each widget below the other one. So, if you use `.grid()` you can manage the widgets position as you like. It is easy `widget.grid(row = 0, column = 1)` this is an example of usage.